# Using zlib's convenience methods on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, zlib, compression

Is it expensive, performance wise, to use the zlib convenience methods to decompress gzipped JSON data as it is being received? Or would I be better off piping the data to a zlib object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally better to use streams wherever possible, but the result of decompressing the response will be the same, as you said.

There are however a few main things that change by waiting until the end to decompress.

1. You incur extra memory overhead because all of the request data must be buffered in memory before decompressing it.
2. You have the extra CPU overhead of having to to concatenate it all together.

For a low-load service, neither of these probably matter, but in the long run they can affect performance and functionality.

What if you wanted to upload and decompress a 2GB video on server with one 1 GB of RAM? The first point would make you simply crash due to lack of memory, and the second means that even if you had the RAM, you'd have to copy around a Gig of data before you even got to the point of decompressing.

By using the streaming API, you can decompress the chunks as they come in and immediately write them to the filesystem or a DB or S3 or something.

Comment: In my case, I only ever receive JSON in the ~1-10kb range. So what's only left is the overhead of doing zlib.gunzip() all the time on the responses. I'm not even sure how the zlib module works but I've been thinking that these convenience methods come with the tradeoff of supposedly instantiating the engine all the time, which is what I assume to be the "overhead", and that streams mitigate this. I've tested it with streams and zlib only calls the data event once, hence no chunks. But I'm still not sure on this engine instantiation stuff (or if its even real).

Comment: `zlib.gunzip` just creates a stream internally and reads all the data before triggering the callback. The overhead is just extra RAM and CPU usage. If the data is small, using the convenience methods will probably be just as fast. I'd still suggest using the stream methods though, because there is no reason not to.